# Show loading spinner on click of link button asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to use this code on a link button, but because it expects the use of a form it is not working. I wish to show the overlay div when I click the link button, so the user has a idea of the long the processing time of a function will be. I am trying to follow the example here at http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/289/

I believe the problem is with jquery because it expects a form submission when I just want it to show on the button click. Keep in mind I am doing this in a user control, so maybe it's related to page life cycle stuff as well, but because my link button is not in a form well, it's in the master page, it may not be the issue.

```
$('form').live("submit", function () {
    ShowProgress();
});
```

This is my script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });
</script>
```

Syles

```
  <style type="text/css">


    .modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .loading
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
    }
 </style>
```

My Html and button click

```
<div class="loading" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br />
    <br />
    <img src="~/Images/slateloading.gif" alt="" />
</div>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkExport"  CausesValidation="false" style="margin-top: 5px;" on Height="60" OnClick="lnkExport_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text=" <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-open-file' ></i><br/>Submit Case" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-dark-theme-negative pull-right" />
```

Then, in `page_load` I have this. I need the progress window to show when the `lnkexport` button is clicked.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string script = "$(document).ready(function () { $('[id*=lnkExport]').click(); });";
                 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "load", script, true);
            }
```

Comment: thank you for the edit helping me make the post more clear sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

1. In this case your form doesn't get submitted to the server.
   You should use submit button instead of linkbutton.
2. Check your jquery version, jQuery .live function removed in jquery V1.9. So If you are using latest version, you have to use .on function.

I recommend to use update panel's 'update progress template' to add loading panel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="mainUpdatePanel">
<ContentTemplate>

   <!-- HTML CODE -->

    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="mainUpdatePanel">
    <ProgressTemplate>

        <!-- LOADING SPINNER USER CONTROL -->
        <uc:Uc_Waiting runat="server" ID="Uc_Waiting"/>

    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Please dont try and make a suggestion when you only new and second I cannot use updat progresspanel

Comment: What's the suggestion that I made? I mentioned my recommend way to do this. That's it.
I also have mentioned about the issues of your code as points.